# Unable to redirect to page using window.location

Tags: javascript

I'm not able to redirect to a single page using windows location in .js page.

However I checked with alert box to see whether the condition is passing true or not and it is working while location is not working.

```
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (email == "test1@gmail.com" && password == "test1") {
        alert("Login successfully");
        window.location.href = 'messages.php';
        return false;
    } else {
        attempt--; // Decrementing by one.
        alert("You have left " + attempt + " attempt;");
        // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
        if (attempt == 0) {
            document.getElementById("email").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I feel I'm missing something.

Comment: assign full path to window.location.href

Comment: @HiteshKansagara: There's absolutely no need for that.

Comment: what error do you get in console

Comment: nothing. it simply says: LOgin successfull" and redirects to same page.

Comment: How are you calling `validate`?

Comment: in another php page, where onclick submit form

Comment: Every submit is reloading the page if I am not mistaken. You can verify by just keeping the network tab in the Developer Tools open. Is the page reloading. In which case you need to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're calling `validate` like this:

```
<form onsubmit="validate()" ...>
```

That won't use the return value of `validate` to cancel the submit. You need a `return`:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()" ...>
```

Since the submission is not being cancelled, the form submission is a navigation action, which overrides your assignment to `window.location.href`.

In a comment you've said you're doing this:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validate()" class="btn-secondary">Sign In</button>
```

If so, adding the `return` to the `onclick` should fix it on any modern browser:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return validate()" class="btn-secondary">Sign In</button>
```

**But** I would move it to an `onsubmit` on the `form` instead.

---

Side note: There's no need for the `type="submit"` on that button. `submit` is the default type for `button` elements.

Comment: i did like this.. `<button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validate()" class="btn-secondary">Sign In</button>`

Comment: @TharunN Put that in the question.

Comment: Re the last part of the answer: Changing to `type="button"` will also solve the problem, since it won't submit the form.

Comment: @Barmar: True, although there's a path through `validate` that doesn't `return false`, so I assumed they wanted to submit in that case...

Comment: Hey can i forward any var value through that window location tag to other page? @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @TharunN You can add URL parameters like `messages.php?name=value`. You can also save variables in cookies, localStorage, sessionStorage.

Answer (score -1):

```
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (email == "test1@gmail.com" && password == "test1") {
        alert("Login successfully");
        window.location.href = 'messages.php';
        return false;
    } else {
        attempt--; // Decrementing by one.
        alert("You have left " + attempt + " attempt;");
        // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
        if (attempt == 0) {
            document.getElementById("email").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
        }
        return false; // ALWAYS return this. else it will proceed with page submit.
    }
}
```